# Spring boot override prod properties from additional location file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-properties

In my application I have these properties files:

> application.properties
> application-prod.properties

Inside I have the same property

> spring.datasource.password=my-dev-password #for the default one
> spring.datasource.password=${PROD_DATABASE_PASSWORD} #for the prod file

On the server I run my application like :

> java -jar "myjar.jar" --spring.profiles.active=prod

Everything works fine so far.

Now I want to use an extra file to override the same property on the server like :

> java -jar myjar.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod --spring.config.additional-location=file:/to/folder/application.properties

but it didn't work !

I've tried to pass it as a java property but it didn't work neither !

> java -Dspring.config.additional-location=file:/to/folder/application.properties -jar myjar.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod

What I have missed here ?

---

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

---

I'm using spring-boot `2.3.5`

---

**UPDATE**

When I reference only the folder it works :

> --spring.config.additional-location=file:/to/folder/

I thought that it takes only folder in contrary to `spring.config.location` but when I've looked to the code both are loaded with the same code in [ConfigFileApplicationListener](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/235e48683cd35f3c87340f1655be8924fd42ebff/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.java#L696) :

```java
private Set<String> getSearchLocations() {
    Set<String> locations = getSearchLocations(CONFIG_ADDITIONAL_LOCATION_PROPERTY);
    if (this.environment.containsProperty(CONFIG_LOCATION_PROPERTY)) {
        locations.addAll(getSearchLocations(CONFIG_LOCATION_PROPERTY));
    }
    else {
        locations.addAll(
                asResolvedSet(ConfigFileApplicationListener.this.searchLocations, DEFAULT_SEARCH_LOCATIONS));
    }
    return locations;
}
```

Comment: When you use the updated config --spring.config.additional-location=file:/to/folder/. I believe it still loads your props from default one and not from the file present in additional-location?

Comment: yes `spring.config.additional-location` overrides those in the jar  `application.properties`

Comment: I played around for some time with my Spring Boot 2.3.4 application. It is working for me. Something you could try ro debug. Rename the file in spring.config.additional-location to other.properties (or something different from Spring defaults) and try if this has an impact. Double check, if you are using proper path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Profile Specific Properties take precedence over default/additional properties. For reference [spring-boot external config](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config).

You can also see the same in Code
[ConfigFileApplicationListener.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/235e48683cd35f3c87340f1655be8924fd42ebff/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/config/ConfigFileApplicationListener.java#L356)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties
```

In more details refer this [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).